# Calling man with redirected stdin to show help from within a BASH script

Tags: bash

Is there any reason why using `man` with redirected stdin to show help from within a BASH script is a bad idea or not compatible with all (within reason) versions of BASH?

The technique works fine with the 2 versions of BASH that I have easy access to: GNU BASH v. 4.3.11 and 4.3.30 (both on Linux). It seems to me an elegant way to display help for a script, from within the script, when the people who download it are not particularly likely to bother installing the man page, and the man page has already been written.

Below is a bare-bones example of what I mean. The `display_usage_message` function would get called when the help option is used on the command line and the script would call `exit` when the function returns.

```
#!/bin/bash

display_usage_message()
{
man /dev/stdin <<EOF

.TH SCRIPT 1 "01 Oct 2015" "1.0" "SCRIPT VERSION 1.0"

.SH NAME
Script \- whatever it does.

.SH SYNOPSIS
script options etc.

.SH DESCRIPTION
This is a description which is not very long. :)
EOF
}

display_usage_message
exit
```

Thanks.

**EDIT:** In light of chepner's comment, would this slight variation be reliable?

```
#!/bin/bash

display_usage_message()
{

temp_man_filename=$(mktemp -q -t "tmp.man.page.XXXXXX")

cat <<EOF >>$temp_man_filename

.TH SCRIPT 1 "01 Oct 2015" "1.0" "SCRIPT VERSION 1.0"

.SH NAME
Script \- whatever it does.

.SH SYNOPSIS
script options etc.

.SH DESCRIPTION
This is a description which is not very long. :)
EOF

man $temp_man_filename

rm $temp_man_filename
}

display_usage_message
exit
```

Comment: The version of `man` that ships with OS X doesn't seem to work with a here document: `fgets: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Error reading man page /dev/stdin`. (The source of the error seems to be the underlying *roff processor.)

Comment: Thanks chepner. Does the variation I've added in my question edit work?

Comment: Thanks for running the tests. Anyone else got any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: It's probably pretty unexpected and unusual behaviour, and novices may not know which keys to press to page forward and exit, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is for the help message to be a short -- ideally, less than a screenful -- reminder of the available functionality, while the manual, conversely, should explain concepts and document error messages, exit codes, operational constraints, etc.

More fundamentally, keeping some or all of the documentation embedded in, or coupled with, the source code is good practice, actively promoted e.g. in Knuth's [*Literate Programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literate_programming) and practiced (perhaps less strictly and formally) by e.g. Perl [POD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Documentation) and Javadoc authors.

Incidentally, `man` markup feels somewhat obscure in this day and age. Perhaps you would want to explore POD or Markdown as friendlier, more modern alternatives (though not quite as versatile for advanced use). POD is easy enough to embed in shell scripts, and formatting tools will be installed anywhere you have Perl.